# What should I name instances of a twisted.internet.defer.Deferred?

Tags: twisted, deferred

I'm writing code using Twisted, and having trouble coming up with a sensible variable name for my twisted internet deferred's.  Here are my candidates:

- `d` : Too generic, too short, violates pylint rule C0103.
- `def` : Conflicts with function defintion builtin.
- `defer` : Conflicts with module twisted.internet.defer
- `deferred` : OK but pretty long
- `cb` : Still too short, violates pylint C0103, conflicts with many callback method names.
- `cback` : Too Weird?
- `callback` : Conflicts with method Deferred.callback()

I'm looking for other suggestions.  It seems like most of the Twisted example code uses "d" which is fine for simple invocations, but when you're passing Deferred's around to methods and storing them as member variables, it's really far too descriptive.

Answer (score 3):

It's good to name the `Deferred` meaningfully - as of course you would name any variable.

A good thing to name it after is the event that its firing signals.

Some examples:

```
pageGotten = getPage('http://...')
whenAuthenticated = client.authenticate(...)
taskDone = doTask(...)
```